# I need some examples for understanding the concept of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-functions

Here is the definition of measurable function from Stein and Shakarchi's *Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces* (p.28):

[image]

1. Talking about [-∞,a] for all a *seems like* [-∞,∞]. So one would think why not simply say $f^{-1}([-∞,∞])$ (which is actually E) is measurable (and this would make a useless definition). Could you please provide examples showing how these two definitions differ?
2. Does the range of f need to be measurable? If not, please give me an example.
3. What is a neat example of a non-measurable function (whose domain is measurable)?

Edit: I think this would make a better definition. However it's apparently limited to finite valued functions.

[image]

Comment: Since for a function $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ the set $f^{-1}[-\infty, +\infty] = E$, requiring that this set is measurable is really no extra condition at all.

Comment: @Joppy, Exactly, I added that to my post.

Comment: Right, so can you now see why requiring that all the preimages of $[-\infty, a)$ for various $a$ is a different condition? They should be subsets of $E$, and requiring that each of these subsets are measurable is somehow saying that $f$ is cutting up $E$ into measurable bits.

Answer (score 4):

"Measurable" is the minimal requirement of a function to even *think* about its Lebesgue integral. You might have seen Wikipedia's page, and in particular the following picture;

[image: Lebesgue integration]

The lowest picture describes Lebesgue's integration. There, the base of every rectangle is a set of the form 
$$\tag{1}
\{x\ :\ \lambda_1\le f(x)\le \lambda_2\},$$
and the integral is defined as the "sum" of all such rectangles, with a suitable limiting process involved.

In particular, to even think about integrals it is necessary that the area of the sets (1) is well-defined, and so, it is necessary that these sets are all measurable. It turns out that, to ensure such measurability, it is necessary and sufficient that the sets 
$$
\tag{2}
\{x\ :\ f(x)< a\}
$$
are all measurable. Therefore, we say that $f$ is *measurable* if all the sets (2) are.

Answer (score 2):

1.

Saying that some expression $p(a)$ that depends on $a$ is true "for all $a$" mean, in mathematics, the following:

> Whatever value of $a$ you choose to put into the expression, the statement will always be true.

Therefore, the statement

> For all $a\in\mathbb R: f^{-1}([-\infty, a))$ is measurable

is the statement:

> Whatever value you choose $a$ to be, the set $f^{-1}([-\infty,a))$ is measurable.

This is not the same as saying that $f^{-1}([\infty, \infty])$ is measurable. The statement says that $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}([-\infty, 0))$ is measurable and $f^{-1}([-\infty, 2))$ is measurable and $f^{-1}([-\infty, 3242))$ is measurable and $f^{-1}([-\infty, \sqrt2)$ is measurable and $f^{-1}([-\infty, \pi))$ is measurable and $f^{-1}([-\infty, e))$ is measurable and $f^{-1}([-\infty, 2348+\frac{\sqrt[e]{\pi})}{\ln(398453)})$ is measurable and so on and so on.

2.

The definition does not *demand* that the range of $f$ is measurable.

3.

An example of a non-measurable function would be any indicator function of a non-measurable set.

Comment: Is the domain of the function in part 3 is not a measurable set, right? So that's not what I asked.

Comment: @Asmani The domain is $\mathbb R$, a measurable set.

Comment: ahhh, I see, thanks!

Comment: @Asmani I am talking about the function $\chi_A$, defined as $$\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if} x\in A\\ 0&\text{ if} x\notin A\end{cases}$$ where $A$ is a non-measurable set. Clearly, the domain of $\chi_A$ is the whole of $\mathbb R$, since $\chi_A(x)$ is defined for every real number.